# Behavior of after() method inside a for loop in Tkinter GUI

Tags: python, tkinter

In my sample GUI code, I want to print two different string one after another multiple times. I want some time duration between each string print on the console. I used root.after() method for this and iterate inside 'for loop' to achieve multiple time print.
Here is my code.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *

def display1():
    print('hello world!')

def display2():
    print('hello there!')

def print_it():
    for i in range(2):
        root.after(7000,display1)   #to print after seven second.
        root.after(7000+5000,display2)  #to print after five second of first sentence print.

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("testing")
root.geometry('100x100')

btn = tk.Button(root,text='click it',command=print_it)
btn.pack(side = TOP)
root.mainloop()
```

The problem is in spite of printing one after another, both strings are printing together and not after a given time. I cannot understand the behavior of the after() method. What am I doing wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: You have scheduled two times to call display1 seven seconds later and call display2 twelve seconds later, so you should get two "hello world!" after seven seconds and two "hello there!" after twelve seconds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's look at this code:

```
def print_it():
    for i in range(2):
        root.after(7000,display1)
        root.after(7000+5000,display2)
```

Let's assume that "now" is 12:00.000. When this code runs, the first iteration of the loop will schedule something for 12:07.000, and then another one at 12:12.000. This process maybe takes a millisecond or two. Let's assume it takes 10 milliseconds

The second time through the loop we're now at 12:00.010 since the first iteration took 10ms, so you then schedule something to run at 12:07.010, and then again at 12:12.010.

So now the "after" queue looks like this:

- display1@12:07.000
- display1:12:07.010
- display2@12:12.000
- display2@12:12.010

It's important to remember that `after` schedules a job in the future relative to the current moment, not relative to the previous time `after` was called.

Answer (score 0):

As per above answer I understood the behavior of root.after() method i.e. In the background, root.after() is added to the event loop, but with the condition that it shouldn't be executed until at least 7 seconds (for this case) from when after() was called. During those 7 seconds, any other events in the queue will be executed first. The command might be executed later than 7 seconds, depending on what's being processed already in the event queue, but no sooner.